# Are there multiple copies of Global variables in Swift 4.x/5.x? If so, how do you stop that?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

Scratching my head quite a bit on this one and can't figure this out - hopefully someone can help or explain before all my hair is gone!  Any advice or solution would be most appreciative.  Apologies in advance for the length of this question

My App keeps up with what to display in its tableView with a Global variable (ok, maybe not the best design, but that's not the point of this) an array of structures or classes, it doesn't seem to matter

```
 class Section {
     var sectionDate : String
     var sectionData : [CeuEvent]
     var isVisible : Bool = false {
     // added these to verify isVisible is being changed.
         willSet(isVisible) {
             print("About to set isVisible to \(isVisible)")
         }
         didSet {
             if isVisible !=  oldValue  {
                 print("Added \(isVisible) - \(oldValue)")
             }
         }
     }
     init(sectionDate: String, sectionData: [CeuEvent], isVisible: Bool) {
         self.sectionDate = sectionDate
         self.sectionData = sectionData
         self.isVisible = isVisible
     }
 }
 var sections : [Section] = []
```

The tableView sections all start out as collapsed (isVisible == false)

The tableView section header has a tappable label, with a tag value = the section number and a gesture recogniser attached.  The action for the recogniser gets invoked as expected:

In TapGestureRecogniser sections[label.tag].isVisible is checked for the isVisible value and as expected, it is false.

```
 (lldb) po sections
 ▿ 1 element
   ▿ 0 : <Section: 0x600002181dd0>

 (lldb) po sections[0]
 <Section: 0x600002181dd0>

 (lldb) po sections[0].isVisible
 false
```

then isVisible is toggled - and verified in the debugger

```
 (lldb) po sections[0].isVisible
 true
```

tableView.reload() is invoked.

In tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int), section[0].isVisible is tested

```
 (lldb) po sections
 ▿ 1 element
   ▿ 0 : <Section: 0x6000021d2ee0>

 (lldb) po sections[0]
 <Section: 0x6000021d2ee0>
```

and it's back to being false.

```
 (lldb) po sections[0].isVisible
 false
```

It seems the var sections:[Section] is now at a different memory address, perhaps a copy when isInvisible is updated in the TapGestureRecogniser, and back to the original when responding to numberOfRowsInSection() as indicated by their memory addresses:

memory value of sections and section[0] in TapGestureRecogniser action after being set to true:

```
 (lldb) po countLabel.tag
 0

 (lldb) po sections
 ▿ 1 element
   ▿ 0 : <Section: 0x600001805d40>

 (lldb) po sections[0]
 <Section: 0x600001805d40>

 (lldb) po sections[0].isVisible
 true
```

in numberOfRowsInSection() - isVisible is back to false

```
 (lldb) po sections
 ▿ 1 element
   ▿ 0 : <Section: 0x6000018cc480>

 (lldb) po sections[0]
 <Section: 0x6000018cc480>

 (lldb) po sections[0].isVisible
 false
```

It doesn't matter if var sections is wrapped in a struct and made static or even added to AppDelegate and accessed appropriately - the isVisible value keeps changing back to false.

Comment: Show the code where you update sections. Add a `didSet` to `sections` and set a breakpoint to find out where you are assigning a new array to it

Comment: Please create a minimal project to reproduce the issue and show whole code of it.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the suggestion.  But I don't think that wouldn't have illuminated the problem.

After the tapnotificaton was called and visible updated in the struct for that section, I figured it might be important to reload that section by calling

```
tableView.reloadSections([countLabel.tag], with: .automatic)
```

Doc says "Reloads the specified sections using a given animation effect."

thinking that's the appropriate thing to do, and it that might do what the function name implies, reload the specified section by calling numberOfRowsInSection() for ONLY the specified section, in this case, the one section involved in the transition.

But, noooo, that seems to trigger a complete tableView reload which invokes numberOfSections() and causes the sections array to be rebuilt with, among other data, the default value for visible which is false.

Thanks again for taking a look.

Now to figure a way to persist the visibility state of each section without destroying it on each reload.  Probably going to have to go with add / remove rows.

Any suggestions welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Please include any afterthoughts that show your reasoning in an edit of your original question and not as an answer.